# sum of Fin maps in Agda

Tags: functional-programming, agda

How would I implement the sum of two functions on Fin in Agda with the following type?

```
open import Data.Fin hiding (_+_)
open import Data.Nat

sum : (a b c d : ℕ) → (x : Fin a → Fin b) → (y : Fin c → Fin d) → (Fin (a + c) → Fin (b + d))
sum = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ruben,
there are/might be several approaches to solving your problem (homework? or otherwise?), but here's a specimen problem decomposition:

- in order to use to use the function arguments `x` and `y`, you somehow need to manufacture arguments of the correct type to each of them, from the input(s) available;
- so, you need some way to get from `Fin (a + c)` to *either* `Fin a` (so that you can use `x`), *or* `Fin c` (so that you can use `y`);
- but even then, you're not done, as you then need some way to take the results of applying `x` (resp. `y`) and then transform them into results of the correct type `Fin (b + d)`.

Fortunately, all the necessary pieces to do this kind of decomposition/recomposition are already present in the standard library:

- for 'either/or' reasoning/construction, in `Data.Sum`;
- for decomposition of `Fin (a + c)`/recomposition of `Fin (b + d)`, in `Data.Fin`.

Hope these hints are useful!

Comment: Thanks! Seems so easy now I read your hint. It's not a homework problem. I'm pre-PhD and trying out a few ideas.